# Facebook Graph API mutual_friend_count?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So it seems FQL had a field on each user called **mutual_friend_count**. Is there any way to get this through the graph API?

I can get mutual friends, but I am trying to sort and cull the list when a user has below a certain number of mutual friends. Using 'mutualfriends' with the friends call takes forever and returns way too much data, I only need the count of each user, not a list of every friends mutual friend.

Am I going to have to resort to using FQL to grab this or am I missing something?

EDIT:
So it seems my best bet seems to be FQL - this gives me all my current users friends that have 200 friends in common, ordered by mutual friend count. My question is just whether this can be done directly via the Graph API.

```
SELECT uid, name, mutual_friend_count FROM user 
      WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()) 
      AND mutual_friend_count > 200
      ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Sadly, its really difficult to understand what you are trying to ask!

Comment: The `user` object has a [mutualfriends connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#mutualfriends), but that’ll only give you a _list_ of friends you and someone else have in common, no direct count.